# Randomly display questions in Webform - to use as an exam

Tags: webforms

Is it possible to randomly select a fixed number of questions to display in a Webform? I have a request to set up over 500 questions in a webform but for each user who visits the webform, only a random selection of 100 questions will be displayed. The rest will not be displayed. The purpose of this is to use the Webform as an exam/quiz.

Note: the hidden questions cannot be visible in the code, so CSS or other Javascript hiding techniques are not suitable.

Any ideas how I might achieve it.

Thanks a mil

F

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz module is more suitable for you use case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use form alter to access `$form` array and display/hide specific elements, more details: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-cookbook/how-to-programmatically-hide-and-show-webform-elements.

```
function CUSTOM_MODULE_form_webform_submission_WEBFORM_NAME_add_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $elements = &Drupal\webform\Utility\WebformFormHelper::flattenElements($form['elements']);

  $elements['question_one']['#access'] = FALSE;
  $elements['question_two']['#access'] = FALSE;
}
```